# Where can I purchase air diffusers

Tags: aircraft-design

Where can I purchase the air diffuser located in the overhead compartment of each passenger aircraft seat? I need them for a non aviation application. Thanks

Comment: Seems easy enough to mock-up with a 3D printer.

Answer (score 2):

The technical name appears to be "Eyeball Air Vent". A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=eyeball+air+vent) turned up a number of hits.

Here's an aluminum product from [one manufacturer](http://www.21stcentury-usa.com/aveo/misc/airvent/):

[image]

Here's a plastic model more in line with what you'd see on an airliner, from a [different seller](http://www.aircraftspruce.com/catalog/appages/plasticeyeball2.php):

[image]